# Why isn't the set $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ of all nonnegative real numbers with the usual operations of + and · a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The way I see it $(\mathbb{R_+})$ has an identity element and a zero element as well as it is closed on addition and multiplication.  Yet my textbook lists it explicitly as a non example of a ring.

Comment: It is not a group with respect to addition.

Comment: it doesn’t have additive inverses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a ring, the additive operation must make an abelian group. You don't have additive inverses in your structure, so it is not a ring.

In jest, the kind of structure you have here (where the addition makes a commutative monoid rather than an abelian group) is some times called a [rig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring): It's a ring without negatives, so its name is ring without the n (a more conventional name is semiring). In the same vein, there is what some people call [rng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)): it's a ring without (multiplicative) identity (more conventionally called a non-unital ring).

Comment: lol, I've read of rngs before but not rigs.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly, it looks like I will be impressing my professor with esoteric ring names instead of basic ring knowledge.  Just kidding you have really helped me out here.

Comment: Doesn't the set of all non-negative real numbers have a multiplicative identity?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner They do, but they don't have a negative. Hence they are a rig. A rng, on the other hand, is something like $2\Bbb Z$, the rng of even integers.

Comment: Right; I suppose you meant "there is what" where you typed "you have what"

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, that could've been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb R_+$ is a monoid with respect to addition, but it doesn't have an inverse (since that would be the negative numbers).  So that fails one of the ring conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Just to follow up it fails because, there is no number that can be added to 5, for example, to make it 0, correct?

Comment: @moshebenmaimon Yup!